# How to make the newly appended html code keep the original css style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used bootstrap fpr the design of a webpage. I want to be able to insert a piece of html code into the html template. However, after the insertion, although I specified the class(selectpicker, which is a class in bootstrap) the select belongs to. The newly added select field doesn't have the css style of the selectpicker class. What should I do to make the select field keep the css style without reloading the webpage?

```
// Add a new experiment
$('button[name=addExperiment]').click(function(){
    var existingExperiments = document.getElementsByClassName('experiment');
    var newIndexStr = (existingExperiments.length+1).toString();
    $('div[name=formBody]').append('<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb experiment">'+
                                       '<h4>Question'+newIndexStr+':</h4>'+
                                       '<label> Name*: </label>'+
                                       '<input type="text" name="experimentName" pattern="'+PATTERN_FOR_NAME+'" title="'+PATTERN_FOR_NAME_HINT+'" required>'+
                                       '<br>'+
                                       '<label>Description:</label>'+
                                       '<br>'+
                                       '<textarea class="longInput" cols="30" rows="5" name="experimentDescription" pattern="'+PATTERN_FOR_EXPERIMENT_DESCRIPTION+'" title="'+PATTERN_FOR_EXPERIMENT_DESCRIPTION_HINT+'"></textarea>'+
                                       '<div class="valueType">'+
                                       '<label>Value Type*: </label>'+
                                       '<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-inverse" data-width="auto" name="valueType" title="Choose A Value Type" required>'+
                                       '<option value="Text" selected="selected">Text</option>'+
                                       '<option value="Number">Number</option>'+
                                       '</select>'+
                                       '<div class="valueRange" style="display: none;">'+
                                       '<label>Value Range: </label>'+
                                       '<input type="text" name="valueRange" pattern="'+PATTERN_FOR_VALUE_RANGE+'" title="'+PATTERN_FOR_VALUE_RANGE_HINT+'">'+
                                       '</div>'+
                                       '<div class="valueCandidates" style="display: block;">'+
                                       '<label>Value Candidates: </label>'+
                                       '<input type="text" name="valueCandidates" pattern="'+PATTERN_FOR_VALUE_CANDIDATES+'" title="'+PATTERN_FOR_VALUE_CANDIDATES_HINT+'">'+
                                       '</div>'+
                                       '</div>'+
                                       '<label>Order Number: </label>'+
                                       '<input type="number" name="experimentOrder"  value='+newIndexStr+' min="1" step="1" required>'+
                                   '</div>');
});
```

[image: The select field on the left is the css style of selectpicker class in bootstrap2 while that on the right(which is newly appended is the raw html select)]

Comment: It has the class ***and*** the styles, but `selectpicker` is most likely a javascript plugin that creates the picker when the page loads. In other words, you have to run that plugin again on the new elements.

Comment: @adeneo How to run that plugin again?

Comment: I have no idea, have you read the documentation ?

Comment: Assuming you are using bootstrap-select, take a look at it: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrender

Comment: @Viters Thank you! It perfectly solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help from adeneo and Viters. The cause of my problem is that the selectpicker(rendered by bootstrap-select) is not reloaded after I append the html code. After I add this one line in the end of my code, the problem is solved. [here](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrender) is the link of the related doc.

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
```